# How to convert a KeyCode into a KeyValue

Tags: java, javafx, awt, awtrobot

I am using `JavaFX` to recieve Key input using `.setOnKeyReleased`. The problem is that this gives me a `keyCode`, but to use the `robot class` (tried fx robot but it is "restricted") I need a `keyValue int`.

Is there anyway i can convert a `KeyCode` or `(Fx)KeyEvent` into a `keyValue`? Please help, can not figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try `impl_getCode()` of the KeyCode. But be aware, that this is internal and most probably will change with Java 9. From the KeyCode class:

```
/**
 * @treatAsPrivate implementation detail
 * @deprecated This is an internal API that is not intended for use and will be removed in the next version
 */
// SB-dependency: RT-22749 has been filed to track this
@Deprecated
public int impl_getCode() {
    return code;
}
```

Why this method isn't a proper one, is a mystery.

Use it e. g. like this:

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> {
    System.out.println(e.getCode().impl_getCode());
});
```

If everything fails with the Java implementation changes, you could always just create your own mapping of JavaFX key codes to awt key codes using the Java source.